# ASCII to text conversion different on Chrome than Safari or Opera

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `String.fromCharCode(parseInt(value));` to convert ascii to text from a hidden field. It works fine on Chrome, Firefox, and IE, but not on Safari or Opera. I tried a simple string such as this: `var res = String.fromCharCode(72, 69, 76, 76, 79);` and it works fine across browsers. The ascii is converted to `HELLO`. But when I try something more complicated, it no longer works. I'm wondering if it might be that the ascii is different for different browsers. I could be totally wrong.

Note: by not works, I mean when I do console.log(answer), the answer is garbled. `9ods?` appears instead of `God's Masterpiece Matthew 15:99 Psalms 129:158` which is what it should be.

Here's a code snippet with that specific part of my code:

```
var arrHiddenAnswer = $('.hiddenAnswer').val().split(',');
var answer = "";
$.each(arrHiddenAnswer, function(key, value){
    answer += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(value));
});
console.log(answer: "+answer);
```

Here's the hidden field from the form I'm working with that I get the hidden answer value from:

```
<input type="hidden" class="hiddenAnswer" name="hiddenAnswer" value="071,111,100,039,115,032,077,097,115,116,101,114,112,105,101,099,101,032,077,097,116,116,104,101,119,032,049,053,058,057,057,032,080,115,097,108,109,115,032,049,050,057,058,049,053,056">
```

If it helps, here's the test page with what I'm working on:
http://playfuldevotions.com/archives/140

Thanks in advance!

Edit: if there's a better way of encrypting an answer then getting its value, please feel free to share.

Comment: Using leading zeroes and `parseInt` without an explicit base 10 is looking for trouble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply a radix to [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```
> parseInt("071") // oh, leading zero, must be octal!
57
> parseInt("071", 10)
71
```

Comment: I would vote up, but I don't have enough reputation yet.